# I can dd array but it goes back as null when I return it. Laravel5

Tags: php, arrays, function, laravel-5, return

I'm not sure why but I can `dd` an array ***fine*** but when I want to return it, it goes back as `null`. When I setup this if-statement, it always goes back as `[1]`

```
public function getEventInterestAttribute($event_interest){
    dd($event_interest);// //it gets printed OKAY here
    if ( ! $event_interest || empty( $event_interest ) ) { //IT PASSES THIS CONDITION and always gets returned as [1] WHY??
        $event_interest = [1];
    }
    return $event_interest;
}
```

What am I missing ?

This is the result of `dd`:

```
array:5 [
  0 => 28
  1 => 17
  2 => 13
  3 => 24
  4 => 2
]
```

Comment: `( ! $event_interest` will always pass ... what is it anyways you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Function works fine - https://3v4l.org/jl57D, I suppose you show us not the real code you have a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the `empty()` function; it will check whether the array is empty or the variable `$event_interest` is `null`, `false` etc... (Documentation for the `empty()` function can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)) Try this:

```
public function getEventInterestAttribute($event_interest){
    dd($event_interest);
    if ( empty( $event_interest ) ) {
        $event_interest = [1];
    }
    return $event_interest;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should assign the values as ,

$event_interest = array(1);

and return it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what the function "empty" dose,

but try to print the array in the if

and after the dd

in another words try to run this code:

```js
public function getEventInterestAttribute($event_interest){
    dd($event_interest);// //it gets printed OKAY here
    console.log($event_interest)
    if ( ! $event_interest || empty( $event_interest ) ) { //IT PASSES THIS CONDITION and always gets returned as [1] WHY??
        console.log($event_interest)
        $event_interest = [1];
    }
    return $event_interest;
}
```

if the print befor the "if" is not the same as the print in the "if" blam the "empty" function.

Comment: This is __not__ javascript. Question has `php` tag.